# How to take screenshot of a complete web-page with powershell?

Tags: powershell, screenshot

I want to take snapshot of entire web-page with the help of Powershell. I have a code that can give me screenshot of currently active system window but my powershell currently opens web-pages in background in another Internet Explorer Instance. Is there any way to take the web screenshot with powershell.

Comment: This might help: http://obscuresecurity.blogspot.ch/2013/01/Get-TimedScreenshot.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[A PowerShell tool for taking screenshots of multiple web servers quickly.](https://github.com/dafthack/PowerWebShot)

**PowerWebShot**

A PowerShell tool for taking screenshots of multiple web servers quickly.

**Requirements**

This tool utilizes Selenium and PhantomJS to screenshot web servers. I've included the phantomjs.exe and Selenium WebDriver.dll in this repository but if you would like to download them directly from their sources they can be found here:

The phantomjs.exe and WebDriver.dll must be in the current working directory of the PowerWebShot.ps1 script.

**Usage**

PowerWebShot can be used to screenshot a single URL with the -URL option or a list of URL's from a file with the -UrlList option. Each web server will have a thumbnail generated and added to an HTML report at report.html in the output directory.

First, run powershell.exe and import the script with:

```
C:\PS> Import-Module PowerWebShot.ps1
```

**Screenshot a single URL**

This command will take a screenshot of http://www.google.com and add it to a file called report.html in an automatically generated directory with the current date/time as the folder title.

```
C:\PS> Invoke-PowerWebShot -URL http://www.google.com
```

**Screenshot a list of URLs and output to a custom directory**

This command will take a screenshot each of the URLs in the file "urllist.txt" and add them to a file called report.html. Each screenshot and the report will be located in a directory called "web-server-screenshot-directory".

```
C:\PS> Invoke-PowerWebShot -UrlList urllist.txt -OutputDir web-server-screenshot-directory
```